# How to fix Eclipse C++ run error "Program file doesn't exist."

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, mingw-w64

I am trying to run the `Hello World` C++ program in Eclipse. It says `Building Test Debug` then `Launching Test Debug has encountered a problem. Program file doesn't exist.` Is it because some required files are missing? How would I get these files? I have been using MinGW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the `Debug` folder where my program binary was and ran it. It required `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll`, `libstdc++-6.dll`, and `libwinpthread-1.dll` to run. So, I added those libraries to Eclipse from MinGW using `Project` -> `Properties` -> `C/C++Build` -> `Settings` -> `Tool Settings tab` -> `linker` -> `Libraries`.